# Changing between two xsessions is very slow if external monitor is connected

Tags: xrandr, displayport

If I login via lightdm into an xmonad session and then switch to another user, two xsessions are running and I can switch between them via `ctrl`+`alt`+`f7` resp. `f8`.

This is very fast (< 1s) on my laptop if no external screen is connected. However if I use an external monitor via displayport switching is very slow (> 10s). What may be the reason for this and how can I fix it?